# Import on MongoDB Compass Community Edition?

Tags: mongodb

I noticed there are three (3) versions of MongoDB Compass.

1. Enterprise
2. Community Edition
3. Read-only

I want to import a JSON or BSON files, which software should we use? The website does not say much (https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/). The read-only, is obviously for reading only.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

Answer (score 0):

Both enterprise and community editions will allow you to import JSON. Compass does unfortunately not have support importing BSON. For that, you'll have to use `mongorestore`.